# How can I shapechange as an evil Tainted Sorcerer without dying?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sorcerer, taint

My PG is a Tainted Sorcerer with high taint score and I have the evil subtype, so this does not kill me.

If I cast Shapechange I would lose my evil subtype and I would die unless I choose a monster with evil subtype or undead, right? Is there a way to retain the evil subtype using shapechange?

If I instead first cast Infernal Transformation and then Shapechange afterwards, what will happen?

Comment: Tainted sorcerer is one of the most horribly broken classes in the game; I cannot more strongly recommend that you find some other method of realizing this character.

Comment: My GM starts a campaign with all published of 3.5 edition , all manuals , all Dungeon Magazine and Dragon Magazine .....no sense and with no ban.....except inifinite combos.
We have one charging fighter that can do 4k damage with 1 charge...and he has wraithstrike and another broken warrior that has 16 atks in 1 turn i do not know how.
This is the level of the campaign ,  so i am trying to build a mage class that is broken to not remain behind my mates. 
This is only the third time that i play D&D ...so i am very confused how to build .

Comment: And shapechange is one of the more broken spells in the game. Scary combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shapechange.htm)

> You also gain the type of the new form in place of your own.

So, in order to retain evil subtype your new form must have it, though you won't die of high taint since [Tainted Sorcerer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/taint.htm#sorcererTaintSuppression) doesn't apply the taint as a penalty to *Con* score.

[Infernal Transformation](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/infernal-transformation-lesser) does modify your type, but if you modify it again with a *Shapechange*, your previous modification is forfeit. Other than a little bonus to your *Str* and *Con* it doesn't give you much in this setup.

Comment: In Heroes of horror , there is an "update" to tain rule : Creatures with the “Evil” subtype and undead creatures are immune to any negative effects from taint. They automatically have effective corruption and depravity scores equal to one-half their Charisma score, +1 for undead or +2 for outsiders. They take no penalty from these taint scores, but they can use them to qualify for feats or prestige classes.
So my taint  can be raised with the tainted sorcerer and i do not have negative effects.